# How to add bootstrap 4 active class on nav-item?

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add an active class on my .nav-item when the user clicks on a page from the navigation menu. This is my jquery code which I found on stack overflow.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".nav-item").on("click", function(){

        $(".collapse").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

    });

});
```

And here is my html nav code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown2" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon navbar-toggler-icon-dark"></span>
                            <span class="fas fa-times hide"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="/"></a>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown2">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('index') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about') }}">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('how-it-works') }}">How it Works</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('pricing') }}">Pricing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('faq') }}">FAQ</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="searchBox"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                    </nav><!-- nav -->
```

My problem is slightly different than others on stack overflow. For some reason when I inspect the element I can see that it adds the active class, but then it disappears right away. I think this might have something to do with the page being refreshed? There are no errors in the console, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You can't do it like this, because when you click the link, you go to another page (or refresh the current). So this script works but after refreshing the page, everything goes back as it were before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('index') ? 'active' : '' }}">Home</li>
```